# store array list in shared preferences with the type of an object

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have an array list of `list_beneficiaries` (type: Beneficiary). In that array list I have elements like of type Beneficiary object. Something like this,

```
list_beneficiaries.add(new Beneficiary(Integer.parseInt(obj2.getString("id")),
                       obj2.getString("ben_firstname"), obj2.getString("ben_lastname"));
```

I want to add this arraylist in shared preferences and retrieve it. How can I do that?
I tried with this stackoverflow answers: [Save ArrayList to SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences)

But, I am not getting the result I want. Because I have an array type of object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save ArrayList to SharedPreferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences)

Comment: @Selvin : i have already mentioned that link into my question..

Comment: @Selvin : You know what? If you don't wana help somebody or you don't know anything then you should just get out of here. I already mentioned in my question that `I tried` those answer. I need more explanation with that.

Comment: @Selvin : I didn't ask you to do translation of my comment though. Did I?

Comment: anyway (lets bury the hatchet), one hint ... SP for list is a bad choice, once you modify one object you have to serialize whole array again and save it to SP ... try to use SQLite instead especially if you think/assume/are sure that there will be more than just few elements in the array...

Comment: @Selvin : I got the solution from below answer. Thanks. And sorry for my rude behaviour. There are just few elements, that's why I am not using SQLite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really like Gson. It's easy to use:

1. [Download the jar](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-2.2.4-release.zip&can=1&q=) and save to `app/libs/`.
2. Update gradle dependencies (build.gradle):

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
   }
   ```
3. Update your code:

   ```
   ArrayList<MyClass> array = new ArrayList<>();

   SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

   // Put
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   String json = gson.toJson(array);
   editor.putString("preference_key", json);
   editor.commit(); //every change in editor object is commited.
   // Get
   json = prefs.getString("preference_key", null);
   java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyClass>>(){}.getType();
   array = gson.fromJson(json, type);
   ```

Comment: Seconded for the Gson solution. Have used it myself with great effect.

Comment: What's `PREF_MEM_SEARCH`?

Comment: Name of the shared preference file

Answer (score 0):

*Use this and instead of `ArrayList<String> use List<YourObjectClass> or ArrayList<YourObjectClass>`*

```
  public void saveArrayList(ArrayList<String> list, String key){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);
    editor.putString(key, json);
    editor.apply();     // This line is IMPORTANT !!!
}

public ArrayList<String> getArrayList(String key){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = prefs.getString(key, null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```